# sed/awk search for pattern in string on one line and change pattern in string on another line

Tags: awk, sed

In an F5 bigip.conf text file, there are hundreds of virtual server entries as below. I need to change the route domain from 701 to 703 but only when the virtual server destination address contains 10.166.201. - **10.166.201.48%701**

```
sed '/10\.166\.201\./s/701/703/' bigip.conf
```

My issue now is that the subsequent source nat entry **"source 0.0.0.0%701/0"** also has to change but only for instances that fall within the first search criteria .i.e when the virtual server destination address contains 10.166.201

Should be matched and changed:

```
ltm virtual /Common/vip_181_vs {
destination /Common/10.166.201.48%701:81
ip-protocol tcp
mask 255.255.255.255
persist {
    /Common/sbe017_81_cookie {
        default yes
    }
}
pool /Common/sbe017_81_pool
profiles {
    /Common/oneconnect-32 { }
    /Common/swt_http { }
    /Common/tcp_3600 { }
}
rules {
    /Common/rule_dev
}
source 0.0.0.0%701/0
source-address-translation {
    pool /Common/natpool-701_swt_cfr_v0081
    type snat
}
translate-address enabled
translate-port enabled
}
```

Should *not* be matched or changed:

```
ltm virtual /Common/vip_182_vs {
destination /Common/10.155.201.44%701:81
ip-protocol tcp
mask 255.255.255.255
persist {
    /Common/sbe017_81_cookie {
        default yes
    }
}
pool /Common/sbe017_81_pool
profiles {
    /Common/oneconnect-32 { }
    /Common/swt_http { }
    /Common/tcp_3600 { }
}
rules {
    /Common/rule_dev
}
source 0.0.0.0%701/0
source-address-translation {
    pool /Common/natpool-701_swt_cfr_v0081
    type snat
}
translate-address enabled
translate-port enabled
}
```

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your Input_file is having multiple `Destination` and `Source` strings and you need to check each time the condition if a `Destination` string is having specific value or not then following may do the trick.

```
awk '/your_ip/{sub(/701/,"703");flag=1} flag && /source 0\.0\.0\.0/{sub(/701/,"703");flag=""} 1'  Input_file
```

In case you want to save the output in Input_file itself then do following:

```
awk '/your_ip/{sub(/701/,"703");flag=1} flag && /source 0\.0\.0\.0/{sub(/701/,"703");flag=""} 1'  Input_file  > temp_file  && mv temp_file  Input_file
```

Where your_ip is your address and escape eg--> `.` as `\.` in it too.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will the flag only match one (the next) instance of the subsequent "source 0.0.0.0" match?

Comment: @user1776732, it will each time get set whenever it sees your string it will set, also I will change IP to a text in solution not good to have it in solution.